# Wyse Simple Imager. Unable to Create Product Directory

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I am trying to submit a post on [www.technicalhelp.de](http://www.technicalhelp.de), but I receive an error:

> Invalid Session. Please resubmit the form.

This happens if I delete temporary internet files and log out and back in, and if I use a different browser, and if I use a proxy browser.

*Perhaps someone on this forum can help*

I am trying to push a Wyse device image to a USB thumb drive.  The image is on a remote server, and the thumb drive is connected to my desktop PC.  I am using Wyse Simple Imager to do this.

When I select the following:
Product: V90
Image Version: 5.010627.512
Image File: \servername\folder\OLD_Rapport\V90-withusb\9V90.i2d

Almost instantly, without attempting any action, I receive the message:

> WyseImager
>   Unable to Create Product Directory.  Add Image Failed

I have completely formatted the USB drive with FAT32.  It is new out of the fox, and I can create folders in it.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to try:

1) If the device has U3 or similar, use the USB drive manufacturer's utilities to remove it or get a different device
2) Try copying the image to your local machine rather than pulling it over the network
3) Use the USB Firmware Tool available on wyse.com
4) USB Firmware Tool and WSI will not work on Win7, use XP 32-bit

Hope that helps,

--Cameron

Answer (score 1):

I will pay someone to image my 9150se with XPe. I'm effin sick of this WYSE BS and their cluster-phuc system. Just spent the last 5 hours first trying the PXE image first with WSI (<-- funny how they dared use the word SIMPLE in anything that has to do with their thin clients), and then WDM (or something), faiL faIL fAIL FAIL. I might have to just reinstall Win7 on my laptop from all the schit I've installed from WYSE just to image this little solid state (yet highly convenient) P.O.S.

Then, I find out they have a USB Imager.... which, through all attempts to download I receive a CRC (bad zip) or corrupt zip error. THEN, I manage to have my brother who's 2,000 miles away download it, FTP it to me (after I set up IIS, port fwd's etc...). Then I finally managed to get the USB imager to put my image on; take it over to the WYSE 9150se and WHOA!... it's actually doing something. I'm thinking it DIDN'T work because I literally screamed out loud "holy schit it's actually going to work!!!". Shortly after, I get a message saying "unable to open image file to read size of flash drive". [giggle]. So, let me get this straight. The maching is able to attempt to open the image file but yet it has no idea of the size of my flash drive? WHITE FLAG. [throws hands up in the air and goes to get a beer...] eff this schit.